# Rails, user account and case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, case

I've got a strange problem with my user model in Rails 3.0.5.

When a user registers, case is view by the model: "Nicolas" is different from "nicolas".
When a user login, case is not view by the model: "Nicolas" and "nicolas" are the same.

In my model:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :username

def self.authenticate(username, password)
    user = find_by_username(username)
    return user if user && user.status == 1 && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt) 
    return nil
end
```

So "find_by_usename" will return the first user found for "Nicolas" or "nicolas"...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, in MySQL, where are case insensitive.

So, if you want to do a case sensitive search, try something like this :

```
Model.where('my_string LIKE BINARY ?', "This is a Test String")
```

In your case, this will be :

```
user = User.where('username LIKE BINARY ?', username).first
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly. I just add ".first" at the end of the request.